# How to disable html validator in vscode

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

[image]

**Error message**: `Button type should be 'button', 'reset', or 'submit'.`

I use angular and don't want it to show me an error

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the `setting.json` file in **VS Code** and restart it

```
"html.validate.scripts": false
```

here you go for the `setting.json` file

Menu File → Preferences → Settings

Answer (score 0):

You van use *Angular2-Inline* plugin. Or maybe *Angular Language Service* plugin.